# $index is tracking elements which are hidden by ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

```
<tr ng-repeat="materialOffer in Vm.materialoffers track by materialOffer.id" 
    ng-if="!materialOffer.containMaterial && $index >= startIndex && $index < endIndex">
</tr>
```

I have an array of objects named `materialoffers`.  Each element of the array is an object with a property named `containMaterial`.  Some objects have this property `null` while others have it as an object.  I would like to display only those objects which have an object in the `containMaterial` property.  I am also using `$index`, `startIndex` and `endIndex` for pagination.  The problem that I am having is that `$index` is tracking those objects as well that have `containMaterial` property `null` for example the array is like this

```
[{ 
  "object1": {
    containMaterial:obejct;
  }
}, {
  "object2": {
    containMaterial:obejct;
  }
}, {
  "object3": {
    containMaterial:Null;
  }
}, {
  "object4": {
    containMaterial:obejct;
  }
}]
```

When traversing object4, the `$index` would be 3 while it should be 2 since object has been hidden by `ng-if`.

Comment: Can we see the way you're tracking the objects

Comment: you want to see whats inside the <tr>?

Comment: Tracking the page so as to offer an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pre-filter beforehand?

In your HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="materialOffer in Vm.filteredMaterialOffers() track by materialOffer.id"
    ng-if="$index >= startIndex && $index < endIndex">
</tr>
```

In your JS:

```
$scope.Vm.filteredMaterialOffers = function () {
    Vm.materialoffers.filter(function (x) {
        return x.containMaterial ;
    });
};
```

Comment: yeah actually i was thinking of it,but i was just curious to know if there is anything alternate to $index that tracks only those templates in ng-repeat that are shown,not hidden by ng-if hide or anything.Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: use built in `limitTo` filter instead of `ng-if`